# Issue with lateinit in test case

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, junit

I have a kotlin Ut like below

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
internal class FileOpenerTest {

    private val file = mockk<Resource>()
    private lateinit var target: FileOpener

    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
        val file = File("./src/test/resources/sample.csv")
        every { file.file } returns file
        target = FileOpener(file)
    }

    @Test
    fun `get  documents for indexing from  file`() {
        val docs = target.startIndexing()
        verify { docs.size == 3 }
    }
}
```

the test case is always failing saying

**kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property target has not been initialized**

But I am initialising it in the setup method, please help me to fix the issue ?

Comment: Shouldn't `@BeforeAll` be used on *static* methods? You probably want to use `@Setup` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup annotation `@BeforeAll` is applied only on static functions:

> @BeforeAll annotated method MUST be a static method otherwise it will throw runtime error.

[Source](https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/before-all-annotation-example/)

So your method is not executed in JUnit. Either put the method and the field in your companion object or initialize it differently, like with `@Before`

Comment: In kotlin there is no static keyword. Also there is an existing UT which is working fine with @BeforeAll.

Comment: 1. Thats why I suggested to put it inside `companion object`. 2. Did you debug the test file and could reach initilisation inside `@BeforeAll` before your test starts?